# How to find the largest numbers in an unordered array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I need to find the largest number in an unordered array (javascript)

```
[[-34, -54, -74], [-32, -2, -65], [-54, 7, -43]]
```

This should be the result -> `[-34, -2, 7]`

I have tried this:

```js
let brojevi = [
  [-34, -54, -74],
  [-32, -2, -65],
  [-54, 7, -43]
];

let pronadjiNajveciBroj = (brojevi) => {
  let najveci = brojevi[0];
  for (let i = 0; i < brojevi.length; i++) {
    if (brojevi[i] > najveci) {
      najveci = brojevi[i];
    } else {
      console.log("Ovo nije najveci broj")
    }
  };

  return {
    najveci
  };
};
console.log(pronadjiNajveciBroj(brojevi));
```

but I only get the last array as a result

Comment: `brojevi[i] > najveci` makes no sense. Those are arrays, not numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
const a = [[-34, -54, -74], [-32, -2, -65], [-54, 7, -43]];
const r = a.map(e=>Math.max(...e));
console.log(r);
```

a.map() takes an array and returns another array formed by transforming each element (an array in this case) with a function.

Math.max() takes a list of comma-separated values and returns the maximum value.

The spread operator ... yields a list of comma-separated values from an array.

Comment: please update your answer with some dialog that explains how your code works and why it works... remember this is a site others look to for explanation as well. OP may have no idea what `...` does, or higher function `.map()` or `Math.max`, etc...